# vim linebreak after hyphen with gq

Tags: vim

Is there some way to configure vim's gq function so that it allows line breaking after a hyphen (in a compound word)? e.g.

```
twentieth-
century
```

And by the way, I'm not on my own laptop, but on one of the lab, which runs Windows, so any solution not using programs like `par` or `fmt` get bonus points :-) (though I'm also interested in solutions using these tools if this is not possible to do this using only vim -- at least I would be able to do it on my laptop).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a way to get Vim's internal formatting to do this; I think you'll probably be restricted to `formatexpr` or `formatprg` - and writing your own Vim code to duplicate internal formatting with that slight modification is going to be kind of hard... so unfortunately an external program may be the only straightforward way.

Comment: Well, then do you know how to configure `par` for that? (I'm asking this question by pure laziness, I don't want to read the super-long man page of `par` today :-)) Thanks.

Comment: How about add space before or after **'-'**?

Comment: that will fail if par doesn't actually want to break at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ASCII hyphen (0x2d), this isn't possible. If you're able to use Unicode, you can use the identically-looking Unicode variant (U+2010, cp. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) instead. This can be inserted via Ctrl-V (Ctrl-Q on most Windows installations of Vim), followed by `u2010`. Or define a digraph for it:

```
:digraph -- 8208 " hyphen, U+2010
```

With

```
:set formatoptions+=m
```

Vim will

> Also break at a multi-byte character above 255.

Voila! If you need to persist the text as ASCII, you could even write mappings / a wrapper around `gq` that `:substitute`s the hyphens back and forth.

Comment: While en dash is in most fonts identically looking, there is U+2010 HYPHEN character that is semantically correct.

Comment: @ZyX: Thanks, edited that in. The Wikipedia page barely mentions the hyphen.

Comment: Kind of late response but definitely very nice.

Comment: **A clever but ultimately terrible solution.** Keyboards provide a `-` character for a reason. _No one_ is going to use either `<Ctrl-K>--` or `-<Backspace>-` rather than `-`. Muscle memory is deeply ingrained. Moreover, digraph input is extremely keystroke inefficient and hence intended _only_ for infrequently used Unicode characters. Replacing ASCII with superficially similar Unicode glyphs introduces a number of other complications as well, including language-specific UTF-8 encoding quandaries and confusion in other developers. Vim simply needs to support hyphenation out-of-the-box.

Comment: @CecilCurry: If you don't like the overhead of digraphs (and just edit blocks of text, so don't have the need for inserting both hyphen and dashes), a quick `:inoremap <buffer> - <C-k>--` achieves that. With regards to better built-in hyphenation in Vim, you're very welcome to submit such a patch ;-)